# Really Simple Question | JavaScript setTimeout Fails

Tags: javascript, dom-events, settimeout

For some reason I am stuck on this JavaScript `setTimeout` problem. Could someone direct me as to where I went wrong? FireBug gives me an error stating:

> "loadComplete is not defined".

I only have a snippet of it; the part which is having the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadComplete() {
        $('div#formContainer').fadeTo(2000, 1);
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        setTimeout('loadComplete()', 4000);
    }
</script>
```

If it makes any difference I *do* have this loaded in an external JS file.

Comment: Not necessarily your problem, but just pass the function itself to setTimeout (`loadComplete` without quotes). Passing a string like this is essentially an unnecessary `eval`.

Comment: if you just remove the quotes it will actually run the function as soon as it the javascript engine gets to the code... remove the `()` as well, and it will only be called after the timeout :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setTimeout(loadComplete, 4000);
```

that should fix up the problem :)